# Run time Error 1004: Method 'Select' of Object 'Sheets' failed

Tags: vba, excel

I don't know why this is making a run time error. It is supposed to select the sheets in workbook 1 to copy them in workbook 2. Can anyone help me? 
Debugging shows that the error is in the line: "ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Select"

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
If cef.path = "" Then
    MsgBox ("PATH of pictures is required")
Else
    Dim WB1 As Workbook
    Dim WB2 As Workbook

    Dim num As Double

    Set WB1 = ActiveWorkbook
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Item_number").Visible = True
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("CODES").Visible = True
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Item_Number_Hydro").Visible = True
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Select
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Copy
    Set WB2 = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim nombreHoja As String
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must have some **hidden sheets** in the workbook. You cannot select hidden worksheets, and so you cannot `Activeworkbook.Sheets.Select` which attempts to select all the sheets.

[You don't actually need to use `Select`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros). But you *can* copy all the sheets without selecting them, including hidden ones:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.copy
```

Or, copy an array of specific sheets (without `Select`):

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Item_number","CODES","Item_Number_Hydro")).Copy
```